# Code to access Wolfram's REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, rest

Could someone give me an example of code I can use to access Wolfram's API data? I'm not worried about formatting for now--I would just like to learn the basics of interacting with the API.

The Wolfram website FAQ says this: "The Wolfram|Alpha API is designed to operate with interactive web technologies such as AJAX, Flash, and Silverlight."

And the documentation, which is located here: http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html, says this: "A simple API call to retrieve output for the query "pi" would look like this: http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=pi&appid=XXXX
This query did not specify a desired output format, and the default is to retrieve the plaintext and image representations of each subpod. The image is returned as an  tag suitable for direct inclusion in a web page. Here is the output:"

I just have no idea how to put this together to actually access the Wolfram API data. Do I use AJAX or something else? What is the basic code for accessing the data?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=pi&appid=XXXX-XXXX",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml){
        document.write("Success");
      }

    }).then(function(data) {
      document.write("Success");
    });
});
```

I'm very new at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Not an answer, but ***do not*** use `document.write`.

Comment: Also, don't post your *actual* appID.

Comment: I tested your code and it's working...i change the `document.write` with `$("#myDiv").append("Success");`...

Comment: @RobertRozas May I ask where you are testing the code? I am trying it on codepen.io and it is not returning anything. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm testing it it my apache localhost